# Ошибка при установке библиотеки discord.py

Tags: python

при установке discord.py вылетает ошибка ниже. Пробовал полностью переустановить python, результата 0.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Когда же вы научитесь читать *traceback* перед тем как идти сюда... Написано же (в низу 2й картинки и на ней же выше) `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/downloads/`. Переходим по ссылке, скачиваем установщик, выбираем нужные компоненты (не забудьте выбрать комплект 14 версии!) и всё, попробуйте установить модуль заново. Подробнее установка расписана  [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52467429/13435478) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49984619/13435478)

Comment: Если вам не нужна вся VS - можно воспользоваться этой ссылкой https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса